# Why is selenium webdriver Firefox not working for unpriviledged users?

Tags: python, firefox, ubuntu, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use selenium to create screenshots in a Django view in python. The selenium firefox webdriver works well if I start it under root. However, when I try to run it with a non-superuser it freezes when trying to instantiate the driver. Django is called through the apache `www-data` user, so it suffers from that problem.

Is there any way to make the selenium firefox webdriver work as non-root?

From a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install I did the following

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip firefox xvfb
pip install selenium pyvirtualdisplay
useradd testuser
```

And then in a python shell:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://askubuntu.com")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

If I log into python as root, this works fine, if I use the testuser account, the line `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` stales with no response or errors.

I would be thankful for any suggestions of why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Selenium + Firefox on linux. The problem was the linux's user: to run these tests, Firefox need to be able to create a profile (a Firefox's profile). This profile is located at `user_home/.mozilla/firefox/profiles`

So in your case, check that :

- This linux's user is allowed to write in his own home
- In `etc/passwd` check that this user have a default shell, `/bin/bash` by example
- In the directory where your webapp is: try a `$ ls -larth`: if all the files in this are owned by `root`, you can try to change the rights on this folder to allow you non-root users to access it (and then be allowed to run Firefox + Selenium). You can also change the rights to a group and add both root and non-root users to this group

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the HOME environment variable.
The snippet I used before starting Firefox web driver was:

```
if os.environ.get("USER") and os.environ.get("USER") == "www-data":
    os.mkdir("/tmp/www_fake_home/")
    os.environ["HOME"] = "/tmp/www_fake_home/"
```

Which fakes the HOME directory to a writeable one in the /tmp/. For this case it works, but may causes problems in other application, hence beware of unexpected behaviors.